# Remove and append from nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested-lists

I need to take profiles from nested lists, with a fuction that take one input and add or remove a list that follow the rules:

```
alex = ["python","java","c++"]
silvia = ["node","php","ruby"]
kevin = ["c++","js","css"]

people = [alex,silvia,kevin]
container = []


def _params(l,r):
"""l = list r = rule[str] """
   string = r           #this is for save input("programmer for:") not used yet
   range1 = range(0,len(l))
   for caracter in range1:
       for x in l[caracter]:
           if x == r:   #this is var string for imput and _params(l) not used yet
            container.append(l[caracter])
           else:
            people.remove(l[caracter])
            return "success"

_params(people,"python")

print(container)
print(people)
```

then list should be something like this:

```
people = [alex]
container = [alex]
```

And it works, but if i change:

```
_params(people,"node")
```

jump to promt:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "./rules", line 58, in 
>       _params(people,"node")
>     File "./rules", line 46, in _params
>       for x in l[caracter]:
>   IndexError: list index out of range

maybe i'm missing an obvious logic, i'm not trying that you guys debug my code just try understand if i'm wrong in my overall logic.

Edit:

it work properly this way:

```
def _params(lts):
r = input("")
for i in range(len(lts)):
    for i2 in range(len(lts[i])):
        if r in lts[i]:
            container.append(lts[i])
            return none

print("choose option")
_params(people)
```

Comment: What is `y` in `if x == y:`? This does not seem to defined anywhere in the code you provided.

Comment: caracter = iteration on l index
x = iteration of carater index

y = r  it was a typing mistake but in the code is r

i'm trying to say search on people, and in this people search someone who know python, the take this person and add him to "container", in "people" delete all who dont know python.

Comment: So why isn't it defined in your code? Can you update your code so it is complete?

Comment: done, thats the full fixed code so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems overcomplicated. If `container` equals `people` at the end, why calculate them separately?

```
This is one way you can structure your code:

alex = ['python', 'java', 'c++']
silvia = ['node', 'php', 'ruby']
kevin = ['c++', 'js', 'css']

people = [alex, silvia, kevin]
container = []

def _params(lst, r):

    for i in range(len(lst)):

        if r in lst[i]:
            container.append(lst[i])

            return None

_params(people, 'node')
print(container)
# [['node', 'php', 'ruby']]

_params(people, 'python')
print(container)
# [['python', 'java', 'c++']]
```